# how to call parent class mothod

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding, upcasting, run-time-polymorphism

I am studying run time polymorphism, I find one example like this

```
class Bike {
    void run() {
        System.out.println("running");
    }
}

class Splender extends Bike {
    void run(){
        System.out.println("running safely with 60km");
    }

   public static void main(String args[]){
       Bike b = new Splender (); //upcasting
       b.run();
   }
}
```

here Bike class object b can access method run of Splender its okay,
so can we access run() method of Bike? if yes then how? if not then why?

Answer (score 0):

No, it was [overridden](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1) by `Splender`. You use an instance of `Splender`, so its version of the method is going to be used.

You have access to it while overriding it, though.

```
@Override
void run() {
    super.run();
    System.out.println("running safely with 60km");
}
```

> ### [8.4.8.1. Overriding (by Instance Methods)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1)
>
> An overridden method can be accessed by using a method invocation expression (§15.12) that contains the keyword `super`. **A qualified name or a cast to a superclass type is not effective in attempting to access an overridden method.**

Comment: b is object of Bike, then why its not accessing Bike method?

Comment: @dev_swat the actual (or run-time) type of `b` is `Splender` which overrides the method. The declared type of a variable doesn't matter when it comes to method overriding

Comment: "You have access to it while overriding it, though." - just to clarify this a bit: "You have access to [the function] while overriding [the class], though".

Comment: @Quaffel I am not overriding the class, though

Comment: In the example above, you did. There's nothing wrong with it. However, I just wanted to clarify that calling the parent's implementation of `#run()` isn't limited to the scope inside the overridden function. The formulation "overriding the class" might have been a little missleading since it doesn't refer to "overriding" in the classical sense.